# How to find count of Direct Reporting's by DAX formula in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, business-intelligence

Good day! I have a sample employee table like the one below. I need a DAX formula in Power BI to create a measure to count the number of direct reports of each employee. For Example, the Direct Report count of GL0001 will be 2 (Because GL0001 is the line manager of GL0002 and GL0019 and they report to GL0001), the Direct Report count of EMP-02023 will be 3, Direct Report count of GL0002 will be 3. Please help me also to create measures regarding the count of only one direct reporting and less than three direct reporting

```
| Employee ID  |  Line Manager ID  |  Layer (of Employee) |  Layer (of Line Manager) |
|--------------|-------------------|----------------------|--------------------------|
|  EMP-01980   |  GL0003           | 4                    | 3                        |
| EMP-02023    | EMP-02015         | 6                    | 5                        |
| EMP-01636    | EMP-02015         | 6                    | 5                        |
| EMP-02138    | EMP-02162         | 6                    | 5                        |
| EMP-02145    | EMP-01980         | 5                    | 4                        |
| GL0023       | GL0022            | 5                    | 4                        |
| GL0001       |                   | 1                    | 0                        |
| GL0002       | GL0001            | 2                    | 1                        |
| GL0003       | GL0002            | 3                    | 2                        |
| GL0019       | GL0001            | 2                    | 1                        |
| GL0020       | GL0002            | 3                    | 2                        |
| GL0024       | GL0002            | 3                    | 2                        |
| EMP-01918    | EMP-00791         | 9                    | 8                        |
| EMP-01941    | EMP-00791         | 9                    | 8                        |
| EMP-02019    | EMP-02156         | 8                    | 7                        |
| EMP-02024    | EMP-02023         | 7                    | 6                        |
| EMP-02025    | EMP-02023         | 7                    | 6                        |
| EMP-03001    | EMP-02023         | 7                    | 6                        |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data doesn't have all the `Employee ID` for each `Line Manager ID`. That means the `PATH` calculation would not work.

I've assumed your data looks like this

| Employee ID | Line Manager ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1000001 |  |
| 1000002 | 1000001 |
| 1000003 | 1000002 |
| 1000004 | 1000003 |
| 1000005 | 1000004 |
| 1000006 | 1000005 |
| 1000007 | 1000006 |
| 1000008 | 1000007 |
| 1000009 | 1000006 |
| 1000010 | 1000003 |

Creating Calculated columns you can calculate the `PATH` and the `PATH SIZE`

### Path

```
Path = path('Table'[Employee ID],'Table'[Line Manager ID])
```

### Path Size

```
Path Length = PATHLENGTH([Path])
```

## Output

[image]

---

## Edit

In that case, you can use the `Line Manager ID` column to count direct reports, measure below.

### DAX: Calculated Column

```
CountDirectReport = 
VAR EmpId = [Employee ID]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ),
        FILTER ( 'Table', [Line Manager ID] = EmpId )
    )
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply. However , pathlength will not work in this case because I need direct reporting, not the full chain.For example, if 1000001 is the top manager , he has only one reporting line 1000002, so the direct report count for 1000001  will be 1. Now suppose, 1000002 is the second level manager and he has three direct reporting line under him , such as 1000003,1000004 &  1000005,so the direct report count for 1000002  will be 3.

Comment: Question edited, please mark as a solution if it was helpful.